# Extracting href from Nodelist

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

```
var downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*="/Download"]');
```

gives me the NodeList with all elements, but how do I extract just the `href` value from all the nodes as a single array?

I tried `return Array.from(downloadLinks)` but looks like PhantomJS doesn't support ES6 so I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("[href*=" / Download "]"), function (e) {
  return e.getAttribute('href');
});
```

Comment: 1. You query selector attribute is a bit weird there, and 2. why not `[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[href*="/Download"]'), function(e) { return e.href; });`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*="/Download"]');
var arrHREF = []; // create an Array to save hrefs
var i = 0;
for(; i<downloadLinks.length; i++) {
  arrHREF.push(downloadLinks[i].href); // push hrefs in array
}
```

or you can write it in one line as (using the for loop property of declaring variables in execution brackets)

```
for (var downloadLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[href*="/Download"]'), arrHREF = [], i = 0; i < downloadLinks.length; i++) arrHREF.push(downloadLinks[i].href);
```

Comment: Erm I should've been more clear. I'd have done it the same way but since I'm doing this over and over I'm looking for an efficient way and ideally a one liner instead of a for?

Comment: @squint wow, heard of it for the first time, will check it out right now! Thanks.